Flutter: FCM send notification to multiple devices not working
I have connected my project to firebase for FCM notification, and build this function to send notification for all users of my app if the admin press a special button:
void sendNotificationToAllUsers() async {
    var url = Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
    const serverKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

    var headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'key=$serverKey',
    };

    var body = {
      'notification': {
        'title': 'Hey guys',
        'body': 'How are you?!',
      },
      'to': '/topics/all',
      'click_action' : 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
    };

    try {
      var response = await http.post(
        url,
        headers: headers,
        body: jsonEncode(body),
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print('Notification sent successfully');
      } else {
        print('Failed to send notification: ${response.reasonPhrase}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Failed to send notification: $e');
    }
  }

and I have added this script to the AndroidManafist.xml:
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>

but it prints this in the console: Notification sent successfully without sending any notifications!!!
I really searched for that, but didn't catch ideas about sending for many devices in one push from the app not from Firebase console!!!
any help would be appreciated.
Update:
I have been added this line in the very first of the "sendNotificationToAllUsers" function:
await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('all');
But it still prints Notification sent successfully without sending the notification !!!

Did you clients actually subscribe to the '/topics/all topic? You have to write the code for that. It's not an automatic operation.

Oh no, I didn't..
Please tell me how to do it?
Type it as an answer please, and what I should edit in my code else?
@FrankvanPuffelen

I had solved that by updating that function to this:
void sendNotificationToAllUsers() async {
    final messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    await messaging.subscribeToTopic('all');
    await messaging.requestPermission();

    var url = Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
    const serverKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

    var headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'key=$serverKey',
    };

    var data = {
      'notification': {
        'title': notifyTitle.text,
        'body': notifyText.text,
      },
      'priority': 'high',
      'to': "/topics/all",
      'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
    };

    try {
      var response = await http.post(
        url,
        headers: headers,
        body: jsonEncode(data),
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        debugPrint('Notification sent successfully');
      } else {
        debugPrint('Failed to send notification: ${response.reasonPhrase}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Failed to send notification: $e');
    }
    clearControllers();
    update();
  }


From the comments it seems you clients did not actually subscribe to the '/topics/all topic. That's not an automatic operation, but you have to do it in your client-side code.
For an explanation of how to do this, see the documentation on subscribing to topics.

I have tried that, but without any progress, after that I updated the post, you can see.
How can I solve that?

Not subscribing to the topic was clearly a mistake in your approach. There may be more mistakes, but this was one of them. Also see What should I do when someone answers my question? --- I recommend creating a new question for the new state with its own minimal repro. There also give it a try in the Firebase console, to help pinpoint the problem to the client code or the server code.
